# what actually does this keyword in javascript works?

Tags: javascript

Actually i am beginner in `javascript` and i am making a `todo` list with only `javascript` and given is my code..

```
function updateItemStage() {
    var cbId = this.id.replace("cb_", "");
    var itemText = document.getElementById("Item_" + cbId);


    if (this.checked) {
        itemText.className = "checked";
    } else {
        itemText.className = "";
    }
}


function addNewItem(list, itemText) {

    totalItems++;

    var listItem = document.createElement("li");

    var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
    checkBox.type = "checkbox";
    checkBox.onclick = updateItemStage;
    checkBox.id = "cb_" + totalItems;

    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = itemText;
    span.id = "Item_" + totalItems;

    listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
    listItem.appendChild(span);


    list.appendChild(listItem);
}

var totalItems = 0;
var btnNew = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
btnNew.onclick = function() {
    var todoInput = document.getElementById("todoInput")

    var itemText = todoInput.value;

    if(!itemText || itemText == "") {
        return false;
    }
    addNewItem(document.getElementById("todolist"), itemText);
};
```

Using this code i successfully create a `todo list` but in this code i didn't get what is the main role and work of `this` keyword..

can anyone help me please to understand this problem ???????????

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: this link doesn't helped me..

Comment: From the linked documentation: "When a function is used as an event handler, its `this` is set to the element the event fired from [...]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` keyword is the element where your event happens

```
var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
checkBox.type = "checkbox";
checkBox.onclick = updateItemStage;
```

In your case, `this` is the checkBox which you clicked.